# Genome Project Focusing on gene ADRB2?

Tags: genomes, human-genome

I am not sure which project database to use UCSC or Ensembl for my asthma study about ADRB2 gene (Arg/Arg-16 genotype).

I am using the original Human Genome Project database at the moment.
However, I think Ensembl may be better suited for me.

**Which genome database is good for Asthma research for Single Nucleotide Polymorphism (SNP variations)?**
I am looking for something which has existing visualisation tools or one where you can easily write one yourself.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Ensembl has subsections that let you look at a single genomes. The fact that the database has other genomes is irrelevant.  What are you calling the "original Human Genome Project"? Do you mean UCSC? What kind of data do you want to visualize?

Comment: I think it can be UCSC that was first out. Tools that give overview of the database and let me then focus on some sample.

Comment: There is actually no difference between the databases, as they use the same datasets. Only the way you can display and look at the data is different. I like Ensembl more, but this is a flavour. And I got a pretty good introduction to it.

Comment: @Masi, _all_ of them do that, that's the point og a genome browser. Can you please edit your question and narrow it down? I still don't know what you need that neither the UCSC nor Ensembl offer you. The only way to choose between them is personal choice or specific tools provided but since you don't explain what you want to do, it's hard to help.

Comment: @terdon Thank you for feedback! I pickup the gene Arg/Arg-16 which I am browsing in infantile asthma.

Comment: I ask again, please clarify. Arg/Arg16 is not a gene, its a genotype; I think the gene you mean is ADRB2. You still have not told us what is missing from the tools you are using. You have not explained what exactly you want to visualize nor what exactly you are looking at. I am beginning to guess you are after SNP variations but I'm not sure. You mention vertebrates, does that mean you want to do a comparative analysis of some sort? Please [edit] and be more specific.

Comment: Thank you for helpful comments! I focused the question even more. Just ADRB2 and SNP.

Comment: So you are looking for a way to find mapped SNPs in the ADRB2 gene?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for variations in a gene, there are a few databases you an consult.

You can of course use the usual genome browsers, search for your gene and then select the variations listed. For ADRB2 this looks like [this](http://www.ensembl.org/Human/Search/Results?q=adrb2;site=ensembl;facet_feature_type=;facet_species=Human) on Ensembl. If you plan to retrieve and compare data from different genomes/genes, I really recommend learning how to use [Biomart](http://www.ensembl.org/biomart/), as this is a very powerful tool.

Then you can use specific databases or search engines, which only target SNP's. Examples would be: [DBSnp](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/SNP/) and [SPSmart](http://spsmart.cesga.es/) (which queries different databases).

Comment: Very clear and excellent answer! Thank you for mentioning those tools! I am in the beginning of reviewing and learning them. :)

Comment: You're welcome. BTW: If you have the chance of participating in one of the Ensembl courses, do it. It is definitely worth the time.

Comment: I will do it when my studies go to Clinics phase.